# Hardy-Littlewood inequality in $L^p$ space.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $p \in (1, \infty]$ and $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
I would like to show that if $Mf(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{m(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|df$, then for all $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
$$m(\{x:Mf(x)> \lambda\}) \leq  \frac{3^n}{\lambda^p}||f||^p_p, $$
where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.
We know that for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
$$m(\{x:Mf(x)> \lambda\}) \leq  \frac{3^n}{\lambda}||f||_1, $$ I thought I would be able to use this one but I could not figure out how.

Comment: HINT. Use Jensen or Hölder to establish that $$Mf(x)\le (M |f|^p(x))^\frac1p.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, by Jensen's inequality:
$$(Mf(x))^p=\sup_{r>0}(\frac{1}{m(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|\,dy)^p\leq \\\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{m(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|^p\,dy=M|f|^p(x)$$
Thus:
$$m(\{x:Mf(x)>\lambda\})=m(\{x:(Mf(x))^p>\lambda^p\})\leq m(\{x:M|f|^p(x)>\lambda^p\})\leq \\\frac{3^n}{\lambda^p}|||f|^p||_1=\frac{3^n}{\lambda^n}||f||_p^p$$